Open sets in inductive limit topology
I'm trying to understand inductive limit topology on the space of test functions $D(\Omega)$, as defined in Rudin's \textit{Functional Analysis}, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-empty open set. The topology is defined as below:

For every compact set $K \subset \Omega$, $\tau_K$ denotes the Fréchet space topology on $D_K(\Omega)$, the space of smooth functions with support in $K$.

Let $\beta$ be the collection of all convex balanced sets $W \subset D(\Omega)$ such that $W \cap D_K(\Omega)$ is $\tau_K$-open for every compact $K \subset \Omega$.

The inductive limit topology $\tau$ on $D(\Omega)$ is the collection of all unions of sets of the form $\phi + W$, where $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ and $W \in \beta$.


I am trying to gain a better understanding of this topology, specifically regarding:
a. What do typical local bases and open sets look like in this inductive limit topology on $D(\Omega)$?
b. How should I visualize the behavior of open neighborhoods around a function $\phi_0 \in D(\Omega)$?
Any insights or illustrative examples that highlight the structure of these open sets in the context of the inductive limit topology would be greatly appreciated!
